# what does conditional Deseasonalize & Detrending mean in pycaret?

Tags: time-series

The time series model in pycaret offers a lot of methods, some of which have w/Cond  Deseascnalize & Detrending. Why exactly does it mean?  Models like ARIMA does not have it.

1. Exponential Smoothing
2. ETS
3. ARIMA
4. Auto ARIMA
5. Passive Aggressive Wi’ Cond. Deseasonalize & Detrending
6. Theta Forecaster
7. Huber Cond, Deseasonalize & Detrending
8. K Neighbors WI Cond. Deseasonalize & Detrending
9. Least Angular Regressor w/ Cond _ Deseasonalize & Detrending
10. Linear w/ & Detrending
11. Ridge w/ Cond. Deseascnalize & Detrending
12. Bayesian Ridge w/ Cond, Deseasonalize & Detrending
13. Elastic Net w/ Cond. DeseasonaEze & Detrending
14. Lasso WI Cond _ Deseasonalize & Detrending
15. Extra Trees w/ Cond, Deseasonalize & Detrending
16. Random Forest w! Cond. Deseasonalize & Detrending